# Qt signals and slots passing data

Tags: c++, qt, signals

I'm pretty new to `c++ and qt`. I'm not sure if i use the right terminology describe what I want to achieve. But here it goes.

My application `spawns and removes widgets in a gridlayout` when the user `pushes buttons`. Managed to do this successfully. However when the user uses the spawned widgets I want the `widgets to interact with each other`.

```
QList<QLineEdit*> m_ptrLEPathList;
QList<QPushButton*> m_ptrPBList;

qint8 m_noFields;

void MainWindow::on_pbIncFields_clicked()
{
    //create widgets and place on a new row in a gridLayout
    QLineEdit *lineEditPath = new QLineEdit(this);
    QPushButton *pushButton = new QPushButton(this);

    //storing pointers in lists to be able to delete them later.
    m_ptrLEPathList.append(lineEditPath);
    m_ptrPBList.append(pushButton);

    ui->gridLayout->addWidget(m_ptrLEPathList.last(),m_noFields,0);
    ui->gridLayout->addWidget(m_ptrPBList.last(),m_noFields,1);

    connect(m_ptrPBList.last(), SIGNAL(clicked(bool), this, SLOT(on_addPath()));
    m_noFields++;
}

void MainWindow::on_pbDecFields()
{
    //delete last spawned widgets
}

void MainWindow::on_addPath()
{
    QFileDialog getPath();
    getPath.exec();

    //somehow set the text of the line edit spawned on the same row as the pushbutton

}
```

So my slot is executed when I push any spawned button but I have no idea how to `store the data from the file dialog in the related lineEdit`.

Is the basic idea of what I'm trying to do ok or is there any other solution to achieve the fuctionality I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `on_addPath` slot you can use `QObject::sender` method to get the clicked button, and, assuming `m_ptrLEPathList` and `m_ptrPBList` lists are equal, you can easily get the corresponding `QLineEdit`:

```
void MainWindow::on_addPath()
{
    QFileDialog dialog;
    if (!dialog.exec())
    {
        return;
    }

    QStringList fileNames = dialog.selectedFiles();
    if (fileNames.isEmpty())
    {
        return;
    }

    QPushButton *btn = qobject_cast<QPushButton*>(sender());
    if (!btn)
    {
        return;
    }

    Q_ASSERT(m_ptrPBList.size() == m_ptrLEPathList.size());

    int index = m_ptrPBList.indexOf(btn);
    if (index == -1)
    {
        return;
    }

    QLineEdit *edit = m_ptrLEPathList.at(index);
    edit->setText(fileNames.first());
}
```

Comment: Yes the list should stay of equal size. Tried your solution and it worked beatifully! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add a map to private section

```
QMap<QPushButton*, QLineEdit*> map;
```

Then

```
QLineEdit *lineEditPath = new QLineEdit(this);
QPushButton *pushButton = new QPushButton(this);
map.insert(pushButton, lineEditPath);
```

You can use sender() method like follow:

```
    void on_addPath()
    {
        QFileDialog getPath();
        getPath.exec();

        QObject* obj = sender();
        QPushButton *pb = 0;
        if((pb = qobject_cast<QPushButton *>(obj)) != 0) {
            QLineEdit* lineEdit = map->value(pb, 0);
            if( lineEdit != 0 )
                lineEdit->setText( getPath.<some function to get selected file name> );
        }         

    }
```

Comment: `sender()` method will return a `QPushButton` that was clicked. Also you code won't compile because you are trying to assign two pointers of incompatible types: `QToolButton*` to `QLineEdit*`.

Comment: My mistake. Sorry guys!... One moment

Answer (score 0):

You are including 'on_addPath' function out of the scope of the 'MainWindow' class, so when the slot is called you have not access to member elements in the class.

Try to include the slot function into the class and check if you have direct access to the member elements. Also, the 'lineEditPath' element must be a member object, so it must be included into the class definition.

Something like this:

```
void MainWindow::on_addPath()
{
    QFileDialog getPath();
    getPath.exec();

    QStringList fileNames = dialog.selectedFiles();
    if (fileNames.isEmpty())
    {
        return;
    }

    m_lineEditPath->setText(fileNames.first());
}
```

Comment: oh the out of scope fuction was just a mistace when I wrote the question. Post edited.

Answer (score 0):

First off, `void on_addPath()` must be `void MainWindow::on_addPath()`

As for linking the data from `QFileDialog` it is simple. Try this:

```
void MainWindow::on_addPath() {
    /* Get the push button you clicked */
    QPushButon *btn = qobject_cast<QPushButton*>( sender() );

    /* Make sure both the lists have the same size */
    Q_ASSERT(m_ptrPBList.size() == m_ptrLEPathList.size());

    /* If the sender is a button in your list */
    if ( m_ptrPBList.contains( btn ) ) {
        /* Get the index of your push button */
        int idx = m_ptrPBList.indexOf( btn );

        /* Get the corresponding line edit */
        QLineEdit *le = m_ptrLEPathList.at( idx );

        /* Get your path */
        QString path = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName( this, "Caption", "Default Location" );

        /* If you path is not empty, store it */
        if ( not path.isEmpty() )
            le->setText( path );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest solution would be to contain the `QLineEdit` and `QPushButton` in a custom widget class, if it suits your project. That way you could use the file dialog inside this class, and you won't have to store the widgets in lists. It is hard to give you all the information, as you didn't really provide any details what your application is supposed to do. But in any case, the custom widget class would look something like this (you should define all the functions inside a `.cpp` file):

```
#ifndef WIDGETCONTAINER_H
#define WIDGETCONTAINER_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QLayout>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QFileDialog>

class WidgetContainer : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
    WidgetContainer(QWidget *parent = 0) : QWidget(parent)
   {
       setLayout(new QHBoxLayout);
       button.setText("BUTTON");
       layout()->addWidget(&lineEdit);
       layout()->addWidget(&button);

       connect(&button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(buttonPressed()));
   }

private:
    QLineEdit lineEdit;
    QPushButton button;

private slots:
    void buttonPressed()
    {
        QString filename = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName();
        lineEdit.setText(filename);
    }    

};

#endif // WIDGETCONTAINER_H
```

Comment: I see where you're going with this solution. It would probably fit my needs well. My application reads upd datagrams with comma separated strings in them. The user-spawned-widgets are for the user to name each field in the incoming string, and to add more fields to the string. When the string arrives the settings provided from the user will be used to format the final display of the data. So there are more widgets on each row than I described in my problem.

Comment: You should probably create a custom widget like this that represents each row. You can even split rows into smaller chunks if you want to, or need to. If the purpose of the line edit and the button is to provide text instead of a file, you should think about using [`QInputDialog::getText`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputdialog.html#getText). It is a static function, so it can be used in the same way as I used `QFileDialog::getSaveFileName();`.

Comment: One of the line edits will be be used to display what directory the user specified with the filedialog. the specified folder is later going to be scanned to check for lastmodified file. Im going to try your solution. It seems like it will clean up my code quite a bit.

Comment: This works really well and looks clean. But how would I solve linking `QRadioButton` between all the spawned widgetcontainers?

Comment: @flog What should the radio button do? In which class does it reside in? Could you just connect a signal to a slot of your spawned widgets?

Comment: Each row of widgetcontainer is used for naming fields in a comma separated string. The radio button is to select one field for special parsing.

Comment: Is there only one radio button or does each row contain a radio button? `QRadioButton` has a [`toggled(bool)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#toggled) signal, which you can use to react on a change made to it. If you need this information inside `WidgetContainer`, and if there is only one radio button, you can connect this signal to a slot of each `WidgetContainer`.

Comment: There is one radio button in each container.

Comment: So where is the problem? You can access it from the container.